# KMeans scatter plot with centroids on timeseries data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm working on a pandas timeseries dataframe which contains 2 columns: timestamp and delta. 
An example is the following one:

```
>> df.head() 
   timestamp             delta 
0  2016-07-30 00:05:00     0.0 
1  2016-07-30 00:10:00  4265.0 
2  2016-07-30 00:15:00  4568.0 
3  2016-07-30 00:20:00  5857.0 
4  2016-07-30 00:25:00  3847.0
```

timestamp contains strings and delta float64. 
I'm trying to run KMeans (sklearn) and plot (using matplotlib) a scatter plot with points and relative centroids.

My code is the follow:

```
delta = df['delta'].values
delta = delta.reshape(-1, 1)
timestamp = df['timestamp'].values

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
km.fit(delta)
km.predict(delta)

plt.scatter(timestamp, delta, c=km.labels_)
plt.scatter(km.cluster_centers_[:, 0], km.cluster_centers_[:, 1], c='red', marker='x')
plt.show()
```

This code returns the following error:

> > IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

On this line:

```
plt.scatter(km.cluster_centers_[:, 0], km.cluster_centers_[:, 1], c='red', marker='x')
```

If I run the code without line with error, scatter plot is correctly plotted. 
I've tried to convert timestamp into float64 but without success.

Can anyone help me on this problem please?

Comment: try printing `km.cluster_centers_` and you will get your answer. It is a numpy array of shape (3,1). It has no second index. It only has `km.cluster_centers_[:, 0]` but no `km.cluster_centers_[:, 1]`

Comment: In other words, since your input data is 1-dimentional, the centroids are also 1-dimensional, you therefore cannot plot an x and a y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for error is that the shape is [3, 1].

You have 3 cluster centroids in one dimension. It does not make sense to cluster-plot first centroid and second centroid as an (x,y) pair. Because all of the centroids in this plot are on the Y axis (because delta is on Y). So you must plot (0, KMC1), (0, KMC2), (0, KMC3).

[Exemplary Visualization](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Y5sV29MdC5PLpDlc2FxADrnLuSYQv0KW)